# Looping main function while resetting variables

Tags: python, loops

Just started learning Python in my computing fundamentals class. We have to build a program that creates practice sets for mathematics. The user inputs two numbers, an operator, then a solution, and the program tells them if they are correct/incorrect. After that, the program is supposed to loop back around so the user can continue practicing. The program is supposed to loop for a total of 5 practice sets. I have the loop, but when it's executed it repeats the inputs initially entered by the user instead of resetting, so the user cannot make any more inputs. What am I missing?

I tried a while True: loop on my global variables but that just causes the main function to loop without completing the program. The assignment very clearly dictates that the use of a while loop is needed, as my professor included slight hints to help us.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter First Input: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter Second Input: "))
op = str(input("Enter Operator: "))
UserSolution = int(input("Enter Solution: "))
res1 = num1+num2
res2 = num1-num2
res3 = num1*num2
res4 = num1/num2
timesCorrect = 0
timesIncorrect = 0

def main ():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 4:      
        print(num1)
        print(num2)
        print(op)
        print(UserSolution)
        counter = counter + 1
```

The function is indeed looping like I want it to, but it isn't resetting the variables like I want it to.

Comment: Just don't use global variables and declare them inside the loop instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your input statements to within the loop, for example:

```
timesCorrect = 0
timesIncorrect = 0

def main ():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 4:
        num1 = int(input("Enter First Input: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter Second Input: "))
        op = str(input("Enter Operator: "))
        UserSolution = int(input("Enter Solution: "))
        res1 = num1 + num2
        res2 = num1 - num2
        res3 = num1 * num2
        res4 = num1 / num2
        print(num1)
        print(num2)
        print(op)
        print(UserSolution)
        counter = counter + 1
```

Also, if you want it to loop five times, you need to change the counter comparison to `< 5`, or `<= 4`, instead of `< 4`.

Comment: Good implementation of adjusting where the inputs go, but your script doesn't tell the user whether they're correct or not.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that the person hadn't gotten to that part of their assignment yet, and was just trying to get the loop working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably going to be a little beyond the scope of your assignment, but here's an untested suggestion:

```
# Mix it up a little by hiding the user's suggested solution with getpass()
from getpass import getpass

### Set iterator variable to avoid hard-coding the script
max_iterations = 5


def evaluate_expression(first_input, second_input, operator):
    """
        Function to handle arithmetic
    """
    my_solution = 0
    if operator == '+':
        my_solution = first_input + second_input
    elif operator == '-':
        my_solution = first_input - second_input
    elif operator == '/':
        # Can't divide by zero, so we have to handle that.
        if second_input != 0:
            my_solution = first_input / second_input
        else:
            my_solution = 0
    elif operator == '*':
        my_solution = first_input * second_input
    return my_solution

def main():

    ### Counters
    correct_guesses = 0
    incorrect_guesses = 0
    try_counter = 1

    while try_counter <= max_iterations:      
        num1 = int(input("Enter First Input: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter Second Input: "))
        op = str(input("Enter Operator: "))
        UserSolution = int(getpass("Enter Solution: ")) # Hide the input

        ### We van evaluate the expression and return the result to a variable using eval()
        # temp_solution = eval(f'{num1} {op} {num2}')

        ## Traditional evaluation method
        #if op == '+':
        #    my_solution = num1 + num2
        #elif op == '-':
        #    my_solution = num1 - num2
        #elif op == '/':
        #    my_solution = num1 / num2
        #elif op == '*':
        #    my_solution = num1 * num2

        # Call our expression and evaluate the results
        if evaluate_expression(num1, num2, op) == UserSolution:
            print('You\'re correct!')
            correct_guesses += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect answer!')
            incorrect_guesses += 1

        try_counter += 1
    print(f'Number of correct guesses: {correct_guesses]\nNumber of incorrect guesses: {incorrect_guesses}')
```